# Why does filling the indices array from a file corrupt the buffer values in Silk.Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading the book **Game Programming in C++** from Madhav Sanjay. I did the exercises in C++ and try to migrate them to C# with the [Silk.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/Silk.NET) library, which is an OpenGL wrapper in .Net: https://github.com/lehmamic/GameProgrammingExercises.

I have a weird behavior while loading the mesh. When I fill in the indices array manually, the indices get transferred to OpenGL correctly (I see that in RenderDoc).

```cs
        var indices = new uint[]
        {
            2, 1, 0,
            3, 9, 8,
            4, 11, 10,
            5, 11, 12,
            6, 14, 13,
            7, 14, 15,
            18, 17, 16,
            19, 17, 18,
            22, 21, 20,
            23, 21, 22,
            26, 25, 24,
            27, 25, 26,
        };

        var vbo = new BufferObject<float>(game.Renderer.GL, vertices, BufferTargetARB.ArrayBuffer);
        var ebo = new BufferObject<uint>(game.Renderer.GL, indices, BufferTargetARB.ElementArrayBuffer);
        var vao = new VertexArrayObject(game.Renderer.GL, vbo, ebo);
```

But when I fill the indices array from a json file content (The indices are stored as an array of array).

```json
{
    "version":1,
    "vertexformat":"PosNormTex",
    "shader":"BasicMesh",
    "textures":[
        "Assets/Cube.png"
    ],
    "specularPower":100.0,
    "vertices":[
        [-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0,0,-1,0,0],
        [0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0,0,-1,1,0],
        [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0,0,-1,0,-1],
        [0.5,0.5,-0.5,0,0,-1,1,-1],
        [-0.5,0.5,0.5,0,1,0,0,-1],
        [0.5,0.5,0.5,0,1,0,1,-1],
        [-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,0,1,1,0],
        [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0,0,-1,0,-1],
        [0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0,0,-1,1,0],
        [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0,1,0,0,-1],
        [0.5,0.5,-0.5,0,1,0,1,-1],
        [-0.5,0.5,0.5,0,1,0,0,-1],
        [-0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0,1,0,-1],
        [0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0,1,1,-1],
        [-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,0,1,0,0],
        [-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,-1,0,0,0],
        [0.5,-0.5,0.5,0,-1,0,1,0],
        [-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0,-1,0,0,0],
        [0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0,-1,0,1,0],
        [0.5,-0.5,-0.5,1,0,0,1,0],
        [0.5,-0.5,0.5,1,0,0,1,0],
        [0.5,0.5,-0.5,1,0,0,1,-1],
        [0.5,0.5,0.5,1,0,0,1,-1],
        [-0.5,-0.5,0.5,-1,0,0,0,0],
        [-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-1,0,0,0,0],
        [-0.5,0.5,0.5,-1,0,0,0,-1],
        [-0.5,0.5,-0.5,-1,0,0,0,-1]
    ],
    "indices":[
        [2,1,0],
        [3,9,8],
        [4,11,10],
        [5,11,12],
        [6,14,13],
        [7,14,15],
        [18,17,16],
        [19,17,18],
        [22,21,20],
        [23,21,22],
        [26,25,24],
        [27,25,26]
    ]
}
```

It gets corrupted somehow. I don't get why, because the content of the array is exactly the same at the end (See the implementation in the [Mesh.cs](https://github.com/lehmamic/GameProgrammingExercises/blob/master/GameProgrammingExercises/Mesh.cs) file).

```cs
        var indices = new uint[raw.Indices.Length * 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Indices.Length; i++)
        {
            var index = raw.Indices[i];
            if (index is null || index.Length != 3)
            {
                throw new MeshException($"Invalid indices for {fileName}.");
            }

            var offset = i * 3;
            for (int j = 0; j < index.Length; j++)
            {
                indices[offset + j] = index[j];
            }
        }
```

I have no clue what that could be.

Comment: @Rabbid76 why are you keep removing the opengl tag? It has something to do with opengl, at the end the indexes arrive messed up in the shader

Comment: You are not using OpenGL directly, but Silk.Net. This is not a question about OpenGL statements. It is a question about Silk.Net. I know OpenGL very well, but I can't help you because I don't know Silk.Net.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm not that sure that it has anything to do with opengl. I just figured out that it seems to work when I draw only one mesh.

Comment: I could fix it.  I extracted the buffer creation and assignment into a BufferObject class. The book doesn't do that. So I changed my code to match exactly the C++ code from the book. There the buffer gets created in the vertex array object class.

```cs
            _indexBuffer = _gl.GenBuffer();
            _gl.BindBuffer(BufferTargetARB.ElementArrayBuffer, _indexBuffer);

            fixed (void* d = indices)
            {
                _gl.BufferData(BufferTargetARB.ElementArrayBuffer, (nuint) (indices.Length * sizeof(uint)), d, BufferUsageARB.StaticDraw);
            }```

Comment: "It gets corrupted somehow" how?